# Как лучше навешивать обработчик события и почему?

Tags: javascript, html5, frontend

Как лучше навешивать обработчик события и почему? 
В HTML теге например

```
<div onclick="deleteProsto()" id="prosto_button">i prosto</div>
```

или навешивать в самом js, нужно быть уверенным что элемент есть и динамически когда создается элемент приходится вешать событие на его родителя

```
document.getElementById('prosto_button').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Как есть подводные камни, с точки зрения производительности читаемости и т.д.?

Comment: третий способ тоже есть на одну строку в js

Comment: такой способ возможен так же   
`$('body').on('click', '.class_or_#id', function(e){});`

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант плох тем, что навешимая функция должна находиться в глобальной области видимости и не позволяет навесить более одного обработчика.
Второй уже лучше, но так же не позволяет навесить более одного обработчика.

Самый лучший вариант использовать `addEventListener`.

Подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)